# Can a suspended user participate in Winterbash?

Tags: support, account-suspension, winter-bash-2013

Can a suspended user participate in Winterbash? Can he/she/it earn hats after he/she/it is suspended? Can he/she/it wear hats after he/she/it is suspended?

Comment: Wanna see first-hand? ;)

Comment: [Noooo..](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GTVEl.jpg)

Comment: Why the *he* in your question? Sooooo gender biased you're ;)

Comment: @R.J Fixed that! ;)

Comment: Bad users don't get gifts from Santa. But sometimes a unicorn will show mercy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1650785/idev) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2226651/java-d) profiles they can wear (or keep already worn) hats even after suspended. So they can participate in Winterbash. But I am not sure if they can earn hats after suspension.

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2909797/monika) also wore hat after I asked this question.

#### Edit:

They can earn hats too even after suspension (mostly passively). See [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2909797/monika) had 4 hats when I asked this question. Now she has 5 hats (she earned Hello, World! hat)

Comment: +1 Here's your [sock puppet hat](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/sock-puppet).

Comment: December 18th, 2013. Suspended User Tim Timmity Tim Tim perverts the suspension process by creating an elaborate system of site participation through frequent hat switches. 2014, Tim Timmity Tim Tim wins the [Ig Nobel Prize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ig_Nobel_Prize) for his contributions to non-verbal communication.

Comment: Good catch on that last user. They definitely put that hat on after the suspension took effect.

Comment: @TheFestivusUnicorn - That means they can only wear/change the hat they already have right? They can't get more new hats as they can't use the site at all(courtesy the suspension, that is).

Comment: @R.J I think there are hats you can earn passively, aren't there?

Comment: @TheFestivusUnicorn - Oh yeah! The secret hats ;) SE is so generous, letting even suspended users have the fun of Winter Bash :)

Comment: @R.J hehe... for example, the up-vote-related hat is given for having only up-votes in a day, from 5+ users; no action would be needed by the user (and up votes are still applied during a suspension, but just don't result in a change in the user's reputation display)

Comment: I think it's because the cross site nature of the hats this year. Suspension is per site, so they can earn the hat on other site where they're not suspended, wear it and untick "only on this site". Mission accomplished. For example, the user you linked to earned "Hello, World!" on parenting site and "42" on movies and TV site.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ahh... interesting!

Comment: Does the whole world need to know that this user was suspended?